# О работе ракеты <=>

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, c++20

Вопрос о том, как *правильно* взлететь на ракете :)

Я об операторе `<=>`. Сначала мне казалось, что это будет что-то простое, вроде `strcmp` - возвращает меньше, больше или равно.

Первое разочарование — что возвращат какой-то "левый" тип, который даже не используешь непосредственно в `if`. Решил, что не очень он мне и нужен, такой странный.

Но недавно попалась заметка, что вроде бы, если определить только его для своего типа, то не нужно писать ни один оператор сравнения. Начал было искать и читать о нем, например, [это](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html) - но видно, мало выпил :( Ясности не добавилось.

Может мне кто-то помочь уяснить, правильно ли я понимаю, что, определив один оператор `<=>`, я автоматически получаю все операторы отношений?

И как верно его определять?

Как бонус :) - почему он такой сложный? Не просто, скажем, возвращающий -1, 0, +1?

Ну, или подскажите, где есть какой-то разжеванный материал на эту тему, желательно, на русском языке.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison Если бы он был прост, то его бы не добавили в С++.

Comment: он не сложен, он прост пытается покрыть кучу вариантов. Есть вещи, которые можно упорядочить строго (например, натуральные числа), а есть вещи, которые сложнее упорядочить (например, отношение между людьми "знаком с "). и оператор <=> (космический корабль) пытается их покрыть.

Comment: @user7860670 Но я все равно не понял, остальные операторы из этого стоятся автоматически или нет?

Comment: @KoVadim Но я все равно не понял, остальные операторы из этого стоятся автоматически или нет?

Comment: оператор равно нужно определить (ну кроме случая, когда используется =default). Мне это решение очень не нравится (оно допускает возможность того, что эти два оператора могут быть "не синхронны", а определять одно через другое - лишняя работа). И во всех доках на этот оператор упоминают раст, пхп и десятки других новомодных языков кроме собственно перла, откуда это и утащили они все.

Comment: @KoVadim А если я напишу `=default`, то он использует `<=>`? А неравенства?

Comment: По ссылке выше можно найти все эти правила.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вызывать `<=>` руками обычно не надо. Но если очень хочется, то его результат можно сравнивать с нулем, примерно как результат `strcmp`. Пример: `(a <=> b) < 0` означает `a < b` (скобки можно не писать). Про его возвращаемый тип ниже.

Если перегрузить `<=>`, написав `= default`, то автоматически будут работать все 6 операторов: `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`. Сравниваться будут все поля.

Перегружать с `= default` можно только в теле класса. На выбор:

```
auto operator<=>(const MyClass &) const = default;
```

```
friend auto operator<=>(const MyClass &, const MyClass &) = default;
```

Если перегрузить `<=>` руками, то будут работать только 4: `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`. Перегрузить `==` нужно отдельно, и тогда `!=` начнет работать автоматически (это работает независимо от `<=>`).

Без `= default` можно перегружать и внутри, и снаружи класса.

Проще всего сжульничать, и написать так:

```
friend auto operator<=>(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b)
{
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y, a.z) <=> std::tie(b.x, b.y, b.z);
};

friend bool operator==(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b)
{
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y, a.z) == std::tie(b.x, b.y, b.z);
};
```

А лучше вынести `tie` в метод, чтобы не писать его 4 раза.

Важно не поддаться искушению и не реализовать `operator==` через `a <=> b == 0`. В общем случае это будет работать медленнее, чем сравнение полей через `==`. (Например, чтобы сравнить две строки через `<=>`, нужен цикл по символам. А `==` может сначала сравнить размеры, и если они разные, больше ничего не делать.)

`operator==` в C++20 тоже можно перегрузить как `= default`. Он будет сравнивать на равенство все поля, и не будет использовать `a <=> b == 0`, даже если вы перегрузили `<=>`.

Если хочется писать `<=>` руками без `tie`, то нужно выбрать возвращаемый тип. В соседнем ответе предложили `int`, и он вроде даже работает, но это как-то сомнительно. На выбор есть три стандартных класса, которые ведут себя примерно как enum-ы:

- [`std::strong_ordering`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering) - больше/меньше/равно
- [`std::weak_ordering`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/weak_ordering) - больше/меньше/эквивалентно - по сути то же самое, но сигнализирует, что разные объекты могут считаться эквивалентными. Пример - сравнение строк без учета регистра.
- [`std::partial_ordering`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering) - больше/меньше/эквивалентно/несравнимо - то же что `weak_ordering`, но добавлено четвертое значение "несравнимо", которое заставляет все 6 операторов возвращать false. Пример: [NaN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) "несравним" с любым другим числом, и с самим собой тоже.

Все три можно сравнивать с нулем: `x < 0` означает `x == ...::less`, и т.п.

В [`<compare>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/compare) есть еще всякие примочки для удобного написания `<=>`, вроде `std::common_comparison_category`, который подбирает подходящий возвращаемый тип по типам сравниваемых объектов.

---

`<=>` можно использовать, чтобы сравнивать объекты разных типов. Очевидно, `= default` в этом случае не поможет.

Компилятор понимает, что порядок операндов не важен, поэтому достаточно перегрузить `A <=> B`, а `B <=> A` заработает само, и все 4 оператора тоже будут работать с любым порядком аргументов.

Аналогично, если перегрузить `A == B`, то `B == A` будет работать сам, и `!=` с любым порядком аргументов тоже.

---

Деталь: На самом деле `<=>` и `==` не генерируют никакие другие операторы. Наоборот, при попытке вызвать другой оператор, компилятор подменяет его на вызов `<=>` или `==`, возможно меняя порядок аргументов.

Разница в том, что, например, нельзя взять адрес такого несуществующего оператора (а-ля `&MyClass::operator<`), и возможно еще в чем-то.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! А нельзя кусочер реального кода с использованием "ваших" типов? Как образец (без `tie`, для какого-то сложного упорядочения)? И еще - эти типы, например, для стандартной сортировки подходят? Или только первый (strong)?

Comment: @Mikhailo Для сортировки подходят все, но partial_ordering не должен возвращать "несравнимо". Без tie... что-то типа `if (auto x = a.x <=> b.x) return x; if (auto x = a.y <=> b.y) return x; return a.z <=> b.z;`. А так, чтобы руками приходилось писать `less`/`greater`/... - сложно придумать.

Answer (score 3):

Как человек практический :), приведу практический же пример переопределения оператора.

Если вас интересует сравнение по полям (типа как в кортеже), то достаточно в классе (для определенности `Test`) написать

```
auto operator<=>(const Test& t) const = default;
```

А если хочется странного, то надо определить этот оператор и оператор `==`.

Например, вот такой класс и сравнение, где четные меньше нечетных.

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(int x):val_(x){}

    auto operator<=>(const Test& t) const
    {
        // Четные меньше нечетных
        if (val_%2 < t.val_%2) return -1;
        else if (val_%2 > t.val_%2) return -1;
        else if (val_ < t.val_) return -1;
        else if (val_ > t.val_) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    auto operator==(const Test& t) const { return (*this <=> t) == 0; }

    int val_ = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Test a(8), b(7);

#define  OUT(a,b) \
    cout << a.val_ << "  <   " << b.val_ << " = " << (a <  b) << endl; \
    cout << a.val_ << "  <=  " << b.val_ << " = " << (a <= b) << endl; \
    cout << a.val_ << "  >   " << b.val_ << " = " << (a >  b) << endl; \
    cout << a.val_ << "  >=  " << b.val_ << " = " << (a >= b) << endl; \
    cout << a.val_ << "  ==  " << b.val_ << " = " << (a == b) << endl; \
    cout << a.val_ << "  !=  " << b.val_ << " = " << (a != b) << endl;

    OUT(a,b);

    a = 7;

    OUT(a,b);

    b = 9;

    OUT(a,b);

}
```

В VC++2019 выводит

```
8  <   7 = 1
8  <=  7 = 1
8  >   7 = 0
8  >=  7 = 0
8  ==  7 = 0
8  !=  7 = 1
7  <   7 = 0
7  <=  7 = 1
7  >   7 = 0
7  >=  7 = 1
7  ==  7 = 1
7  !=  7 = 0
7  <   9 = 1
7  <=  9 = 1
7  >   9 = 0
7  >=  9 = 0
7  ==  9 = 0
7  !=  9 = 1
```

Ну, а использовать ракету в программе можно, например, так:

```
if (auto cmp = (a<=>b); cmp < 0)
    cout << "less";
else if (cmp > 0)
    cout << "more";
else
    cout << "equal";
```

P.S. При этом никто не мешает вам определить свои операторы отношений, в этом случае, понятно, будут использоваться именно они, а не сгенерированные.

P.P.S. Программирование — наука экспериментальная :), так что просто попробуйте поковыряться в коде...